# Is request data already sanitized by Flask?

Tags: python, flask

Should data which comes from the user (like cookie values, variable parts in a route, query args) be treated as insecure and processed in a particular way? Does Flask already sanitize escape input data so passing it to a function `test(input_data)` is secure?

Comment: This is the reason why I ask - I don't know if there is code (passed as bytecode or sth) which could cause code execution, thus if using `unicode` or `int` is enough in cases where unicode/int is expected (rule "Don't trust user input"). "Safe" I mean - properly escaped/sanitized, thus safe in further processing

Comment: It is not sanitized, but this is usually not an issue.  Don't use 'exec' on anything that gets passed in, or use it in raw sql statements, the same as any type of input.

Comment: So question - concrete example: if I want to use query arg which I expect to be unicode - what should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flask does nothing to request data besides parsing it from the raw HTTP request. It has no way to know what constraints an arbitrary function has. It's up to you to check any constraints. All data will be strings by default.  Don't use `eval` or `exec`.  Use your database driver's parametrized queries to avoid SQL injection.  If you render a template with Jinja it will escape data for use in HTML by default.